# How to generate a link for every row/record found in a database to use as a way to populate a form when clicked on?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, forms

I have a website with members and when members are logged in they have access to a page with a form that they can use to submit information.  This form has a hidden input “user_email” with a pre loaded defualt value that is equal to the logged in members email address on file.

```
<form action="xxx.php" class="well" id="xxx" name"xxx" method="post">   

<input type="hidden" id="user_email" name="user_email" value="xxx@email.com">
<input type="text" id="invoice_id" name="invoice_id">
<input type="text" id="other1" name="other1">

<input type="submit" value="Submit">

</form>
```

I need a script that will take that pre filled value of a forms input named “user_email” and search and fetch every row/record of data in my database that have that same value under the “user_email” column.

Then For every row/record matched/found I'm trying to have a link generated

When any generated link is clicked, It needs a function to pre fill the form with its corresponding fetched row/record data.

I cant imagine how much time it would take for one to posses the skills required to compose the code it takes to achieve the above...Any point of direction or any help is greatly appreciated...thanks for your time.

Comment: Just a few tips to start.

You need to fetch all first the records that correspond to user_email.

This will serve as your listing page.


Each row of the list will have the unique primary key fetch from your database.



Next is you can create a detail page where in if you click that row in the list page it will redirect to the detail page holding the primary key.

Answer (score 0):

You could make a request to a PHP script that reads the email, finds the and returns associated data as an array of objects, and outputs the HTML links, with each link containing the data in custom 'data-x' attributes.  For example:

`//email_details.php
<?php
//your function that returns an array of objects
$rows = find_the_data($_GET['user_email']);
foreach($rows as $row) { ?>
<a class="email_data_link" href="#" data-invoice-id="<?php echo $row->invoice_id ?>" data-other1="<?php echo $row->other1 ?>">A link</a>
<?php } ?>`

You could then use a tool like jquery to modify the form when a link is clicked

`$('.email_data_link').on('click', function() {
    //copy the data embedded in the clicked link to the form
    $('#invoice_id').val($(this).data('invoice-id'));
    $('#other1').val($(this).data('other1');
});`

Without additional context and understanding your level of expertise, it's hard to create a truly helpful example, but this may at least give you some food for thought.

Best of luck

Comment: My level is pretty much copy cut and paste...i can piece codes together and edit them kinda but i cant write out code.  When  I read through it, it kind makes sense but some parts I dont get.  Is there any way I can test out code online with a temp or demo database...is there anywhere online where this is possible...like js fiddle but with a database?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of. :-(